# #LC3 Trying to Subtract two number, but the result comes out is not correct

Tags: lc3

```
MySUB   NOT R4,R3 | Flip R3 and load into r4
        ADD R1,R4,#1 | ADD R4 with 1 and load into r1
        ADD R3,R2,R1 | ADD R4 with R1 and load into R3
        RET |Output R3
```

So R2 and R3 it's given in the data, and r3's value is the output value.
My output:

```
009-001=008
004+004=008
008+002=010
003+002=005
001+000=001
005+001=006
009+003=012
008+004=012
000+000=000
002+001=003
```

The Output should look like:

```
009-001=008 
004-004=000 
008-002=006 
003-002=001 
001-000=001 
005-001=004 
009-003=006 
008-004=004 
000-000=000 
002-001=001
```

Comment: Looks right to me. I ran it in a simulator with R2=4 and R3=4, and it ends with the result register, R3, being set to zero.

Comment: In the example output, the operator is always minus. In your output, the output is sometimes minus, sometimes plus. Is there another part of code that is causing this bug?

Comment: Thank you! I finds out the reason could be is r1 and r2 already have value.